# Web server: reading http request from stream

Tags: c#, .net, http

Greetings!

I've been fooling around with C# (again) and now i've stucked with simple HTTP web server implementation. Honestly, i don't want to get along with HTTP specification - i just need to write a very *tiny* (read as *simple*) HTTP web server. And i've encouraged this problem: client sends request to the server and then server parses it, runs some actions, builds response and sends it back to client. That seems to be obvious (for me at least).

Here's what i've got so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 80);
            listener.Start();

            Socket sock = listener.AcceptSocket();

            try
            {
                Stream s = new NetworkStream(sock);
                s.ReadTimeout = 300;

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s);
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(s);
                writer.AutoFlush = true;

                Console.WriteLine("Client stream read:\r\n");

                string str = "none";

                while (sock.Connected && !reader.EndOfStream && str.Length > 0) // here's where i'm stuck
                {
                    str = reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", str, str.Length);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Sending response...\r\n");

                {
                    string response = "<h1>404: Page Not Found</h1>";
                    writer.WriteLine("HTTP / 1.1 404 Not Found");
                    writer.WriteLine("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
                    writer.WriteLine("Content-Length: {0}", response.Length);
                    writer.WriteLine("\r\n{0}", response);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Client: over\r\n");

                s.Close();
                sock.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}\r\nTrace: \r\n{1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

But i've met an "underwater stone": i'm reading request via input stream, so input data flow will be terminated when client close page in his browser (let's talk about the most obvious actions, excluding curl, w3 and other "geek-stuff").

**So, the question is:** how to determine request' end? E.g. when should i stop reading request data and start sending response?

Comment: Why don't you use `HttpListener`?

Comment: 'cause it has not been supported in some of Windows versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message) explains pretty succinctly about the request message format.

> The request line and headers must all end with <CR><LF> (that is, a carriage return followed by a line feed). The empty line must consist of only <CR><LF> and no other whitespace. In the HTTP/1.1 protocol, all headers except Host are optional.

Basically, watch for a blank line after the headers and/or a potential message body.

According to the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html), you can use certain headers to determine if there is a message body:

> The presence of a message-body in a request is signaled by the inclusion of a Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field in the request's message-headers.

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, i'm searching for '\r\n' now. But how could i handle message body?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use HttpListener?  You can have a simple HTTP server in 5 lines of code.

Comment: May be a good idea in some places, but we're not focusing just on a few platforms, aren't we? =)

Comment: Are you trying to say you need to support platforms prior to Windows XP SP2?  If you really want cross platform then maybe Kayak server would be a good option. http://kayakhttp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is this one:
http://webserver.codeplex.com/
even if you don't want to use it, you can stole ideas because it implements the complete request lifecycle.